# MySQL UPPER() and LOWER() not working with utf-8 characters

Tags: mysql

I have a search function, I want it to be case insensitive, including characters like éüò etc.

So, i transform the input to uppercase before querying the database. But MySQL doesn't convert the accented characters right.

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE UPPER(description) = $input
```

I have MySQL 5.1.32, i have tried different collations but none seem to work right. Same with LOWER().

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=187 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"
```

The description field contains 'hellö'. Mysql converts it to 'HELLö'. I want 'HELLÖ'.

Comment: Please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE items`, the value of the `$input` and the value of `name` you expect to match.

Comment: Done! (also changed it to description field instead of name)

Comment: you are using `UTF8_BIN` which is case and accent sensitive. Use `UTF8_GENERAL_CI` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
CREATE TABLE items (id INT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(100) COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT
INTO    items
VALUES  (1, 'Eyjafjallajökull');

SELECT  *
FROM    items
WHERE   name = 'EYJAFJALLAJOKULL';

--
1     Eyjafjallajökull

SELECT  UPPER('Eyjafjallajökull')
FROM    items;

--
EYJAFJALLAJÖKULL
```

Comment: But that's not his point. If I understand him correctly, his issue is that `UPPER("Eyjafjallajökull")` returns `EYJAFJALLAJöKULL`

Comment: But on second thought, this of course fixes his initial requirement so +1 :)

Comment: Weird, this works also for me. Also with MyISAM instead of InnoDB. I don't understand the difference.

Comment: Apparently the contents in the field were not what I thought they were, even though they appeared right in html. Whoops!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone encounters this and have the same issue like me, in my case I found out that my columns where set as varbinary and not varchar by mistake.